# Running Power Automate just to produce a proper schema

Tags: power-automate

The problem I am having with my flow is that I do not have the schema set up correctly.  I have seen a practice in tutorials where the instructor does a preliminary run to the flow just for the purpose of getting the proper schema.  Rather than dig through the tutorials on this, I am hoping someone can give some insight on this practice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your flow, the step before the Parse JSON, get the JSON output (from whichever step you wanted to parse), and use that to create the schema.

When you use the Parse JSON action, there is an option to generate schema from a sample, use that and paste the JSON from above.

Comment: I assume it works because I have a new error now.